# algorithm for finding the lowest cost of an increasing sequence of length 3

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

suppose that we have a sequence of length n. each number in this sequence has a weight. we want to find the least-weighted increasing subsequence of length 3 with dynamic programming. how can we do that?

example:

sequnce : 2 4 5 4 10

weight : 40 30 20 10 40

the answer is 90 ( 2 4 10)

Comment: Can you give sample input and output? Specifically, it's not clear to me if the "sequence" is the weights, or you have 2 numbers for each item, its value and its weight.

Comment: The answer, how did you calculate it? We shouldn’t guess it.

Comment: @someone, Can you please give more details on the constraints, such as the maximum possible value of any element in the sequence array and the sequence array size itself. ?

Comment: what do you want from size?

Comment: you want to give a solution by dynamic programming for this problem ( consider n=3000 and other sizes are big enough that we can't solve it brute forcely)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this exact same problem at some codeforces round. (http://codeforces.com/contest/987/problem/C)

My solution is O(N^2), where N is the number of houses.

It works as follows, for every house k I will search for the cheapest house that belongs to the right of K.

Once I have this information, I just try all possible pairs (i, j) such that height[i] < height[j] and sum to this pair the cheapestHouse that is taller than the house at position j.

Here is my code!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
constexpr int inf = 0x3f3f3f3f;

int main()
{
    int n;
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    cin >> n;
    vector<int> height(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> height[i];

    vector<int> cost(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> cost[i];

    vector<int> cheapestToTheRight(n, inf);

    cheapestToTheRight[n-1] = inf;

    for(int k = n - 2; k >= 0; --k)
    {
        for(int nxt = k + 1; nxt < n; ++nxt)
        {
            if(height[nxt] > height[k])
            {
                cheapestToTheRight[k] = min(cheapestToTheRight[k], cost[nxt]);
            }
        }
    }

    int ans = inf;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if(height[i] < height[j])
            {
                if(cheapestToTheRight[j] != inf)
                {
                    ans = min( ans, cost[i] + cost[j] + cheapestToTheRight[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(ans == inf)
    {
        cout << -1 << endl;
    }

    else cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a link to my submition (http://codeforces.com/contest/987/submission/38734180), but the code is dirtier and with some portuguese variable names on it.